# How can fix the cluster bubbles text overlapping in azure maps?

Tags: javascript, azure-maps

I am using [Azure map Spider Cluster](https://samples.azuremaps.com/symbol-layer/expanding-spider-clusters) in given sample. Everything is working fine in this sample. I also don't want to change in cluster settings, it should be as it is if possible. I just want to display only top cluster bubble's text when cluster bubbles overlap and rest of the cluster bubble's text (which is in the bottom in case of overlap) should be hide. (only bottom bubble's text should be hide, not bubble). Below is my sample code and some screenshots to understand the problem I am facing:

Thank you in advance.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- Add references to the Azure Maps Map control JavaScript and CSS files. -->
    <link href="https://atlas.microsoft.com/sdk/javascript/mapcontrol/2/atlas.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://atlas.microsoft.com/sdk/javascript/mapcontrol/2/atlas.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Azure-Samples/azure-maps-html-marker-layer/main/dist/azure-maps-html-marker-layer.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Azure-Samples/azure-maps-spider-clusters/main/dist/azure-maps-spider-clusters.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        .customInfobox {
            max-width: 240px;
            padding: 10px;
            font-size: 12px;
            margin-right: 20px;
            white-space: normal
        }
        .customInfobox .name {
            font-size: 14px;
            font-weight: bold;
            margin-bottom: 5px
        }
        .popup-content-container .popup-close {
            top: 12px !important;
            right: 6px !important;
            color: #ffffff !important;
            font-size: 16px !important;
            line-height: 18px !important;
            height: 15px !important;
            background: #000000 !important;
            width: 15px !important;
            border-radius: 50px !important;
            display: flex !important;
            justify-content: center !important;
            align-items: center !important;
        }
        .atlas-map-canvas {
            width: 100% !important
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body onload="GetMap()">
    <div id="myMap" style="position:relative;width:100%;min-width:290px;height:600px;"></div>
    <script>
        var map, datasource, popup, spiderManager;
        function GetMap() {
            //Initialize a map instance.
            map = new atlas.Map('myMap', {
                center: [-110, 50],
                view: 'Auto',
                authOptions: {
                    authType: 'subscriptionKey',
                    subscriptionKey: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
                }
            });

            var deviceList = [
                {
                    "id": 8042,
                    "mac": "21june1",
                    "label": "21-Jun-01 - Test-1",
                    "dType": "mp",
                    "latitude": null,
                    "longitude": null,
                    "status": "offline",
                    "space": null
                },
                {
                    "id": 8043,
                    "mac": "21june2",
                    "label": "21june2-Test-2",
                    "dType": "mp",
                    "latitude": null,
                    "longitude": null,
                    "status": "offline",
                    "space": null
                },
                {
                    "id": 8044,
                    "mac": "21june3",
                    "label": "21june3-Test-3",
                    "dType": "mp",
                    "latitude": null,
                    "longitude": null,
                    "status": "offline",
                    "space": null
                },
                {
                    "id": 8045,
                    "mac": "21june4",
                    "label": "21june4 - Test- 4",
                    "dType": "mp",
                    "latitude": null,
                    "longitude": null,
                    "status": "offline",
                    "space": null
                },
                {
                    "id": 7842,
                    "mac": "00c3f407dc6c",
                    "label": "47 Billion",
                    "dType": "tizen",
                    "latitude": 22.685824,
                    "longitude": 75.8722663,
                    "status": "online",
                    "space": null
                },
                {
                    "id": 7934,
                    "mac": "b82e6e318ed3556f",
                    "label": "8f888a7c1385f848",
                    "dType": "mp",
                    "latitude": 22.685824,
                    "longitude": 75.8722663,
                    "status": "offline",
                    "space": null
                },
                {
                    "id": 7953,
                    "mac": "8f888a7c1385f848",
                    "label": "8f888a7c1385f848-kamlesh",
                    "dType": "mp",
                    "latitude": 22.1737063,
                    "longitude": 75.4568386,
                    "status": "offline",
                    "space": null
                },
                {
                    "id": 7949,
                    "mac": "a28f8e61e68b45a6",
                    "label": "a28f8e61e68b45a6 - MS App",
                    "dType": "mp",
                    "latitude": 22.557139462283,
                    "longitude": 75.810245901271,
                    "status": "offline",
                    "space": null
                },
                {
                    "id": 8048,
                    "mac": "45",
                    "label": "ak",
                    "dType": "mp",
                    "latitude": null,
                    "longitude": null,
                    "status": "offline",
                    "space": null
                },
                {
                    "id": 7946,
                    "mac": "a28f8e61e68b45a6123",
                    "label": "App - MS - 2",
                    "dType": "mp",
                    "latitude": 22.685824,
                    "longitude": 75.8722663,
                    "status": "offline",
                    "space": null
                },
                {
                    "id": 8041,
                    "mac": "b25a9ba7d15a",
                    "label": "b25a9ba7d15a-pwa",
                    "dType": "mp",
                    "latitude": null,
                    "longitude": null,
                    "status": "offline",
                    "space": null
                },
                {
                    "id": 8029,
                    "mac": "20180e107277",
                    "label": "COD - Eslide",
                    "dType": "mp",
                    "latitude": null,
                    "longitude": null,
                    "status": "offline",
                    "space": null
                },
                {
                    "id": 7844,
                    "mac": "d003df7e5d96-1",
                    "label": "d003df7e5d96 - Samsung TIzen",
                    "dType": "tizen",
                    "latitude": null,
                    "longitude": null,
                    "status": "offline",
                    "space": null
                },
                {
                    "id": 7969,
                    "mac": "d06d4e782d67ca3f",
                    "label": "d06d4e782d67ca3f - ankit3",
                    "dType": "mp",
                    "latitude": null,
                    "longitude": null,
                    "status": "offline",
                    "space": null
                },
                {
                    "id": 8039,
                    "mac": "53cc155a70d8",
                    "label": "d88d704262ca - PWA",
                    "dType": "mp",
                    "latitude": null,
                    "longitude": null,
                    "status": "offline",
                    "space": null
                },
                {
                    "id": 8010,
                    "mac": "f1sadsa",
                    "label": "f1f1f1msf1f1f1ms-f1f1f1ms-f1f1f1msf1f1f1ms-f1f1f1msf1f1f1msf1f1f1ms-f1f1f1msf1f1f1msf1f1f1msf1f1f1ms",
                    "dType": "mp",
                    "latitude": null,
                    "longitude": null,
                    "status": "offline",
                    "space": null
                },
                {
                    "id": 8046,
                    "mac": "f9846974-24fc-4271-b75a-84a7601c5b7b",
                    "label": "geo Device",
                    "dType": "gf",
                    "latitude": null,
                    "longitude": null,
                    "status": "offline",
                    "space": null
                },
                {
                    "id": 8040,
                    "mac": "d72492ca-5814-4e05-b8ae-b7f8b4cff5ce",
                    "label": "Geo fence Device",
                    "dType": "gf",
                    "latitude": null,
                    "longitude": null,
                    "status": "offline",
                    "space": null
                },
                {
                    "id": 8015,
                    "mac": "6905cdc3-6efb-4727-8305-018244003b18",
                    "label": "GF-AK",
                    "dType": "gf",
                    "latitude": 22.557139462283,
                    "longitude": 75.810245901271,
                    "status": "offline",
                    "space": null
                },
                {
                    "id": 7888,
                    "mac": "grtest1",
                    "label": "grtest - update",
                    "dType": "mp",
                    "latitude": null,
                    "longitude": null,
                    "status": "offline",
                    "space": null
                },
                {
                    "id": 7916,
                    "mac": "hs-test-22",
                    "label": "hs-test-2 edit",
                    "dType": "mp",
                    "latitude": null,
                    "longitude": null,
                    "status": "offline",
                    "space": null
                },
                {
                    "id": 8034,
                    "mac": "785dc8c72f6e",
                    "label": "Left Device\"",
                    "dType": "webos",
                    "latitude": 22.685824,
                    "longitude": 75.8722663,
                    "status": "online",
                    "space": 3897624
                },
                {
                    "id": 7945,
                    "mac": "c0de742442c77ccc",
                    "label": "MS - App\"",
                    "dType": "mp",
                    "latitude": 24.756808311193,
                    "longitude": 72.92724609375,
                    "status": "offline",
                    "space": null
                },
                {
                    "id": 8047,
                    "mac": "mc1",
                    "label": "MS - App\"-1",
                    "dType": "mc",
                    "latitude": null,
                    "longitude": null,
                    "status": "offline",
                    "space": null
                },
                {
                    "id": 8035,
                    "mac": "b4b291180119",
                    "label": "Right Device",
                    "dType": "webos",
                    "latitude": 22.1737063,
                    "longitude": 75.4568386,
                    "status": "online",
                    "space": 3836160
                },
                {
                    "id": 7962,
                    "mac": "91581699f87d1663",
                    "label": "Samsung Tab",
                    "dType": "mp",
                    "latitude": null,
                    "longitude": null,
                    "status": "offline",
                    "space": null
                },
                {
                    "id": 7965,
                    "mac": "e244e6cc9c428e50",
                    "label": "Samsung Tab - release version",
                    "dType": "mp",
                    "latitude": null,
                    "longitude": null,
                    "status": "offline",
                    "space": null
                },
                {
                    "id": 7960,
                    "mac": "ebfd9c9d0931e463",
                    "label": "shivam-mob",
                    "dType": "mp",
                    "latitude": null,
                    "longitude": null,
                    "status": "offline",
                    "space": null
                },
                {
                    "id": 8016,
                    "mac": "8c8d28396f25",
                    "label": "Vipul",
                    "dType": "mp",
                    "latitude": 23.324307764205,
                    "longitude": 69.406630365414,
                    "status": "offline",
                    "space": null
                }
            ];
            var cordinates = [];
            deviceList.forEach(function (item) {
                if (item.latitude != null && item.longitude != null) {
                    cordinates.push({ "type": "Feature", "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [item.longitude, item.latitude] }, "properties": { "Name": item.label, "Status": item.status } })
                }
            });           

            var positions = { "type": "FeatureCollection", "features": cordinates };
            map.setCamera({
                //center map
                bounds: atlas.data.BoundingBox.fromData(positions),
                padding: 50
            });

            map.events.add('ready', function () {
                //Create a popup.
                popup = new atlas.Popup();

                //Hide popup when user clicks or moves the map.
                map.events.add('click', hidePopup);
                map.events.add('movestart', hidePopup);
                //Load customized icons for use with the symbol layer.
                var iconPromises = [
                    map.imageSprite.createFromTemplate('onlineIcon', 'marker', '#4cae4c', '#fff'),
                    map.imageSprite.createFromTemplate('offlineIcon', 'marker', '#808080', '#fff')
                ];

                //Wait for icons to load into the map sprite.
                Promise.all(iconPromises).then(() => {
                    //Create a data source to add your data to.
                    datasource = new atlas.source.DataSource(null, {
                        //Tell the data source to cluster point data.
                        cluster: true,

                        //radius will be always 0.1
                        clusterRadius: 0.1,
                        clusterProperties: { //Calculate counts for each entity type in a cluster
                            'online': ['+', ['case', ['==', ['get', 'Status'], 'online'], 1, 0]],
                            'offline': ['+', ['case', ['==', ['get', 'Status'], 'offline'], 1, 0]]
                        },

                        //The maximium zoom level in which clustering occurs.
                        //If you zoom in more than this, all points are rendered as symbols.
                        clusterMaxZoom: 24,
                        maxZoom: 24
                    });

                    //set data to datasource
                    datasource.setShapes(positions)
                    map.sources.add(datasource);

                    //Create a layer for rendering clustered data in the data source.
                    var clusterBubbleLayer = new atlas.layer.BubbleLayer(datasource, null, {
                        //Scale the size of the clustered bubble based on the number of points inthe cluster.
                        radius: [
                            'step',
                            ['get', 'point_count'],
                            20,         //Default of 20 pixel radius.
                            100, 30,    //If point_count >= 100, radius is 30 pixels.
                            750, 40     //If point_count >= 750, radius is 40 pixels.
                        ],

                        //Change the color of the cluster based on the value on the point_cluster property of the cluster.
                        color: [
                            'case', //Use a conditional case expression.
                            // all offline
                            ['>', ['get', 'offline'], 0] && ['==', ['get', 'online'], 0],
                            '#a5a5a5',
                            // 'rgba(165, 165, 165,0.8)',

                            // all online
                            ['>', ['get', 'online'], 0] && ['==', ['get', 'offline'], 0],
                            '#6aa84f',
                            // 'rgba(106, 168, 79,0.8)',

                            // online and offline both
                            '#ff9900',
                            // 'rgba(255, 153, 0,0.8)',
                        ],
                        strokeWidth: 0,
                        // textOptions:{
                        //     textField: '{point_count}',
                        // },                        
                        filter: ['has', 'point_count'] //Only rendered data points which have a point_count property, which clusters do.
                    });

                    //Create a layer to render the individual locations.
                    var shapeLayer = new atlas.layer.SymbolLayer(datasource, null, {
                        //Define style for individual points. 
                        iconOptions: {
                            allowOverlap: true,
                            ignorePlacement: true,
                            //Use a case expression to select the image icon based on the Status property of the data point.
                            image: [
                                'case',

                                //Check if status is online
                                ['==', ['get', 'Status'], 'online'],
                                'onlineIcon',

                                //Offline/default icon.
                                'offlineIcon'
                            ]
                        },

                        filter: ['!', ['has', 'point_count']] //Filter out clustered points from this layer.
                    });



                    //Add the clusterBubbleLayer and two additional layers to the map.
                    map.layers.add([
                        clusterBubbleLayer,

                        //Create a symbol layer to render the count of locations in a cluster.
                        new atlas.layer.SymbolLayer(datasource, null, {
                            iconOptions: {
                                image: 'none', //Hide the icon image.
                            },
                            filter: ['!', ['has', 'point_count']]
                        }),

                        shapeLayer
                    ]);

                    markerLayer = new atlas.layer.HtmlMarkerLayer(datasource, null, {
                        markerCallback: function (id, position, properties) {
                            //Check to see if marker represents a cluster.
                            if (properties.cluster) {
                                return new atlas.PieChartMarker({                                    
                                    text: properties.point_count_abbreviated                                    
                                });                                   
                            } else {
                                //for single marker
                                return new atlas.HtmlMarker({
                                    visible: false
                                });
                            }
                        }
                    });

                    map.layers.add(markerLayer);

                    //Create an instance of the spider manager.
                    spiderManager = new atlas.SpiderClusterManager(map, clusterBubbleLayer, shapeLayer);

                    //Add event handler for when a feature is selected.
                    map.events.add('featureSelected', spiderManager, function (e) {
                        if (e.cluster) {
                            showPopup(e.cluster.geometry.coordinates, e.shape.getProperties(), [0, 0]);
                        } else {
                            showPopup(e.shape.getCoordinates(), e.shape.getProperties(), [0, -20]);
                        }
                    });

                    //Add event handler for when a feature is unselected.
                    map.events.add('featureUnselected', spiderManager, function () {
                        hidePopup();
                    });
                });
            });

        }

        var popupTemplate = '<div class="customInfobox"><div class="name">{name} ({status})</div></div>';
        showPopup = function (position, properties, pixelOffset) {
            var content = popupTemplate.replace(/{name}/g, properties.Name).replace(/{status}/g, properties.Status);
            popup.setOptions({
                //Update the content of the popup.
                content: content,
                //Update the position of the popup with the symbols coordinate.
                position: position,
                //Offset the popups position for better alignment with the layer.
                pixelOffset: pixelOffset
            });

            //Open the popup.
            popup.open(map);
        }

        hidePopup = function () {
            popup.close();
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Increase your cluster radius setting on the data source. This is measured in pixels. You have it set to 0.1 which is crazy small. The radius should at minimum be the size of your smallest icon/bubble. Looking at your code, 20 looks like a more reasonable minimum number. 30 to 40 is a more commonly range of values used.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but is there any possible way to prevent text overlapping in 0.1 cluster radius. Actually my main motive is to display cluster bubble only when two or more markers are at same coordinates (Lat, Long). So I can't increase radius.

Comment: In the symbol layer, under `textOptions` you can set `allowOverlap` to `false`. This will only show one of the text labels. The other will appear when you zoom in enough for them not to overlap.